# Issue with MVC 3 model binder for propery which is a list of inherited objects

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, deserialization, model-binding

The issue is very similar to this post
[How to implement custom JsonConverter in JSON.NET to deserialize a List of base class objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8030538/how-to-implement-custom-jsonconverter-in-json-net-to-deserialize-a-list-of-base)
However instead of trying to serialize a string manually we are attempting to use the model binding in MVC 3.    So here is the scenario

```
[DataContract]
public class Company
{

    [DataMember]
    public List<Person> Employees { get; set; }
}

 [DataContract]
public class Person
{
     [DataMember]
     public string FirstName { get; set; }
     [DataMember]
     public string LastName { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(Person))]
public class Employee : Person
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Department { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string JobTitle { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(Person))]
public class Artist : Person
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Skill { get; set; }
}

public JsonResult PopulateCompany()
{

    Company model = new Company();
    model.Employees = new List<Person>
    {
        new Employee(),
        new Employee(),
        new Artist(),
    };

    return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    // in the View the model is correctly deserialized. E.g. we can see the properties from Artist


}

public ActionResult PopulateCompany(Company model)
{
    // the returned model is also being populated except the Person object is being added to the Employees and we can no longer access the properties of Artist.
    return View(model);
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The model binding process involve first initializing the model. In your case it initializes an instance of `Company` with a property `List<Person> Employees`. Based on the values that are posted back, if a key/value pair is found that matches a `Person` (e.g. `Persons[0].FirstName: "Ian"`) then a new instance of `Person` is initialized and its properties are set and added to the collection.

The `DefaultModelBinder` has no way of knowing that you want to initialize a different concrete type.

The easy solution is to use a view model containing collection properties of each type (e.g. `public List<Employees> Employees { get; set; }; public List<Artist> Artists { get; set; };` etc).

The alternative (difficult) solution is to create a custom `ModelBinder` that will generate concrete types based on values in the model. [This article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx) (the section on Abstract Model Binder) is a good start for learning how to create a custom `ModelBinder`

Comment: You are exactly correct.  The solution was to create a custom model binder and override BindModel and CreateModel.  In my case detected which model to use based on controllerContext.   Thank you for your assistance.